# Which event to subscribe to intercept application pool recycling?

Tags: .net, application-pool

I need to execute some logging code in my web application every time the application pool is tear down and then tear up. Which events should i subscribe? Application_start and Application_end are triggered only when the application is started/shut down.
Regards,
Register

Answer (score 0):

The event to look at is application end. Another resource to look at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/14/433194.aspx